# what does 's[i]' mean in the code below?

Tags: c++, string

I wanted the ascii value of first character, but `s[1]` is giving something else.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    cin>>s;

    cout<<'s[1]'<<endl;//what will`'s[i]' print as it is not giving ascii!

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't the first character supposed to be `s[0]` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multibyte character constants and bitmap file header type constants](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601430/multibyte-character-constants-and-bitmap-file-header-type-constants)

Answer (score 4):

#### What you are not looking for:

1. `'s[1]'` is a mulitbyte character and is most certainly not what you were looking for.
2. `"s[1]"` is a string containing 4 characters followed by the null character, which is also not what you are looking for.
3. `s[1]` is the second character in the string, which is also not what you are looking for.

#### What you are looking for:

```
int main() {
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(s[0]) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Why not just `static_cast<int>(s[0])`? `reinterpret_cast` is too "strong" in this case I believe.

Comment: Using `reinterpret_cast` for integral types is allowed since c++11. But since reinterpret_cast should be 'reinterpreting the unterlying bit pattern' and 'does not compile to any CPU instructions' the result of casting an integral value to a larger type is not what one should expect (just accessing the char like an int would lead to actually reading four chars starting at the given char; I think that's why these cases have not been handled by pre-c++11 compilers) and a static_cast should be used.